# Commutator is a homomorphism in a nilpotent group of class 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is problem 5.44 in Rotman's "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups", 3rd edition.

> If $G$ is nilpotent of class $2$ and $a \in G$, then the function $[a,\,\,\,]:G \to G$ defined by $b \mapsto [a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is a homomorphism.

What we want to show is that for a fixed $a \in G$ and arbitrary $b,c \in G$ we have $[a,bc]=[a,b][a,c]$, or $a(bc)a^{-1}(bc)^{-1}=(aba^{-1}b^{-1})(aca^{-1}c^{-1})$.

Since $G$ is nilpotent of class $2$, we know that $\gamma_3=[[G,G],G]=1$, and so commutators commute up to being in $\gamma_3$ (in other words, they commute).  I tried using this fact along with trying to expand and collapse the expressions for $[a,bc]$ and $[a,b][a,c]$, but I haven't found a way to do it.  Is there a nicer way to do it than just manipulating these expressions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[a,xy]=a.xy.a^{-1}.(xy)^{-1}=a.xy.a^{-1}.y^{-1}x^{-1}$. In middle of the last word, there is term $ya^{-1}y^{-1}$, so before $y$ if we insert $a$, we get a commutator and since $G$ is class $2$, commutator is in center, hence it can be moved anywhere in product; so

$$[a,xy]=a.xy.a^{-1}.y^{-1}x^{-1}=a.x.a^{-1}\underbrace{a.ya^{-1}y^{-1}}x^{-1} =axa^{-1}x^{-1}.aya^{-1}y^{-1}.$$
What is the last term here?

Answer (score 3):

You should use commutator identity;

$$[x,zy]=[x,y]\cdot [x,z]^{y}$$

As $G/Z(G)$ is abelian $G'\leq Z(G)$ hence $[x,z]\in Z(G)$. Thus, $[x,z]^y= [x,z]$.

As a result $$[x,zy]=[x,y]\cdot [x,z]$$